# How to make the bullets in my unordered list not underlined

Tags: html, css

So I am just learning CSS in my Web Programming 1 class, and the exercise is teaching us about class selectors, so our teacher wants us to make a page which has an unordered listed with only some of the listed items to be underlined. However, when I do this, my bullets in the lists get underlined aswell, where as in the page he wants us to make, they are not.

I've included my code below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style>
            .underline { text-decoration: underline}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Solids </h1>
        <ul>
            <li class= "underline"> Tetrahedron </li>
            <li> Pentahedron </li>
            <li class = "underline"> Cube </li>
            <li> Heptahedron </li>
            <li class= "underline"> Octahedron </li>
            <li class = "underline"> Dodecahedron </li>
            <li class = "underline"> Icosahedron </li>
        </ul>
        <p> What's special about the underlined items.
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The bullets aren't underlined for me.. I'm using Chrome, what browser are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/seWbr/ EDIT.. The bullets aren't underlined in Chrome, FF, IE, or Safari.. (current versions of cource.. just tested)

Comment: create a wrapper element (div or span) inside the li and give it class underline, remove underline from li. I also do not see the under line on the bullets in latest firefox on mac. Usually the list dots are not underlined but maybe some older browsers does this

Comment: Your code is very nice, especially for a beginner. It works fine for me and all looks in order.

Comment: Please paste your code here too. To avoid having just a link here.

Comment: To show us your HTML, and CSS (and JavaScript) in action, use [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), [Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/) or similar. That way you can show how it works, rather than just the mark-up (which should be *in your question* anyway). Out of curiosity: have you specified `list-style-position: outside;` in your `ul, li` properties?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/u45Hf/

Comment: [offtopic] They're special because they're platonic.

Comment: Tell us in which browser are you testing. By the way, "That they are all Platonic Solids" :D

Comment: In fact, it takes [special effort](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/u45Hf/1/) to underline the bullets...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with, Huangism's answer. Adding the span element inside the `<li>` and making that underlined will solve you problem. This way you can colour and style the bullets without effecting the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should give `.underline` class `text-decoration` css property:

```
li.underline{
    text-decoration:underline
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pLnap/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, it must be a browser glitch. Actually, to make a browser display underlined bullets is not that easy. It would have to be something like this:

```
/* this will display underlined bullets. It can also be done in the markup without the second rule and adding an &bull; in between the tags */
 li.underline { 
            text-decoration: underline;
            list-style: none; 
        }

     li.underline:before {
            content: "\2022";
        }
```

The best solution was suggested by @Huangism in the comments. The markup would look like this:

```
<li><span class= "underline"> Tetrahedron </span></li>
<!-- and so on... -->
```

Still, that's a strange glitch. No browser I tested with your markup displays the bullets incorrectly.